# IBus Mandarin pinyin input adds extra letters

Tags: ibus, input-language, chinese, pinyin

I'm using IBus Mandarin input on 2 different computers. On one it works perfectly fine but on the other I get 2 different options for what I type. One is what I'm actually typing and the other is with a bunch of extra letters added. It seems the character it goes for first is based on the extra letter version not my typed one. Is this supposed to happen?

I can't post an image to show what's happening because I don't have enough reputation, but here is a link to a screenshot:

[image: Ibus mandarin]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If I chose iBus Pinyin it seemed it only accepted two keystrokes for each character. So the remaining keystrokes went into creating another character I did not want. If I wrote hao the o went into a new character.

I changed to sunpinyin (which also came with iBus) and it worked.

I also read that [fcitx](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818089/how-to-install-chinese-input-in-english-ubuntu) can be used.