# How to install Chinese input in English Ubuntu

Tags: ibus, input-method, chinese, fcitx, pinyin

I haven't found the right setting for Chinese input, IBus pinyin.
If I want to write "ni hao" the correct alternative shows up after writing "nih" (as second alternative). But if I continue writing "niha" or "nihao" it will show something like "你哈". It seems it does not accept more than two characters per syllable?

I am used to writing the complete pinyin and not checking after every stroke if the correct alternative is in the list. Can I make it work like that?

I tried the [incomplete pinyin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udSA7.jpg) switch, but that was not it. (The input method can not be documented, it will not show up on screenshots.)

Thanks

**Edit** 31/8
The problem was a little different than I first thought, so I changed the question title.
Old title:
Chinese input: IBus pinyin will not accept all letters in syllable

Comment: Have you tried `fcitx pinyin`? fcitx should have better supports for chinese input methods.

Comment: Thanks. I just looked at [fcitx](https://blogs.fsfe.org/stefan.a/2014/09/23/set-up-fcitx-chinese-and-japanese-language-input-ubuntu-14-04/).  The first steps of the [installation](http://imgur.com/a/ppImA) worked fine. But I do not have enough knowledge to fully understand what is happening in step 3 and following. Right now I do a project and I can not risk any malfunction. So I wait a little before I finish this installation.

Comment: fcitx should be defaultly installed in Ubuntu 16.04, you just need to switch from ibus to fcitx in `Language Support` and relogin your account. Then, you will find a little keyboard icon at the right-hand side of your top bar.

Comment: You can also try [this](http://www.voidcn.com/blog/u013013553/article/p-2982668.html) and [this](http://pinyin.sogou.com/linux/).

Comment: The exact steps for switching to fcitx vary between different desktop environments. For Ubuntu with Unity there is an [applicable spot in the official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html#complex).

Comment: If you mean the package ibus-pinyin, it no longer works correctly. You can use ibus-libpinyin instead. After installing (and possibly logging out/in) it will be listed in the input sources as ibus intelligent pinyin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**fcitx** should have better supports for all Chinese input methods.

1. Switch the input system to <kbd>fcitx</kbd> in <kbd>Language Support</kbd>. (If you don't know what is "Language Support", just search it on the dash.)

   [image]
2. Download the latest *Sogou PinYin* fcitx plugin from [this](http://pinyin.sogou.com/linux/).

   [image]
3. Double click to launch <kbd>Ubuntu Software</kbd> to install the `deb` installation pack.
4. Relogin your account.
5. Try to switch to `sogou pinyin` input method under the fcitx input method list in the right-hand side of the top bar.

   [image]
6. Type `nih` or `nihao`.

   [image]
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for all information in thread. It was obviously more than just a setting, I changed the title of the question. I don't think I had fcitx before installing it. (If I try to install again, I get a message that it is already installed. This [list](http://i.imgur.com/yfq4MUt.jpg) was empty under Chinese) Changing to fcitx is a bigger change, so I started by choosing [sunpinyin (iBus)](http://i.imgur.com/HMtnalG.jpg), that seems to work. Later when I can risk some temporary loss of function, I will try fcitx. It comes up as a choice under language support, as described in this answer.

Comment: The blank characters that show up between the character-pinyins (["ni hao"](http://i.imgur.com/HMtnalG.jpg)) are introduced by iBus. To me they are not disturbing. you can just type long and press space at the end and it comes out ok. dajiahaonimenzenmeyang<space> seems to work fine so far, even if (sunpinyin) iBus may not be the recommended IME solution

Comment: Fcitx is only installed by default in Ubuntu 16.04 if you choose one of the CJKV languages at installation. Consequently, for an English system (as is the OP's case) fcitx is not available as an option in _Language Support_ until fcitx has been installed. Please see https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html#complex

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 steps to the process:

1. Add Chinese language support and select IBus input.
2. Logout and back in
3. Add pinyin input method

The following is copied from http://pinyinjoe.com/linux/ubuntu-18-gnome-chinese-setup.htm

**1) Add Chinese Language Support and Select IBus:**

[image]

[image]

Make sure to select IBus as Keyboard input method above.

[image]

**2) Logout and Log back in:**

[image]

**3) Add PinYin Input:**

[image]

[image]